# Java - Resttemplate - POST with multipart/form-data

Tags: java, http-post, multipartform-data, resttemplate, walmart-api

I have to make a POST request to the WALMART API in order to upload my product onto their platform. I have an xml file containing the request to be sent.
My request works in ARC/Postman (can see below example of how the working version is), problem is I cannot make it work in Java using Resttemplate, I simply cannot set the body request (the actual file) properly.

Can you help with 'translating/converting' the request from the below image into Java using Resttemplate?

I have this code so far for setting the above headers(hardcoded some values for security reasons):

```
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("WM_SVC.NAME", "Walmart Marketplace");
    headers.set("WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID", "123456abcdef");
    headers.set("WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP", timestamp);
    headers.set("WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE", signatureString);
    headers.set("WM_CONSUMER.ID", "my-consumer-id-cut-for-security-reasons");
    headers.set("WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE", "my-channel-type");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    headers.set("Host", "https://marketplace.walmartapis.com");
```

and the actual request:

```
File file = new File("C:\\walmartfeed.xml");
DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "text/xml", false, file.getName(), (int) file.length(), file.getParentFile());
fileItem.getOutputStream();
MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts =
        new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parts.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(multipartFile.getBytes()));

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<>(parts, headers);
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MultipartAwareFormHttpMessageConverter());

ResponseEntity<FeedAcknowledgement> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/feeds?feedType=item", org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.POST, request, FeedAcknowledgement.class);
```

Thank you

[this is the link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNuYJ.png)